# Error when parsing parameters for a PUT request

Tags: php, yii

I'm having a problem when I trying to get parameters from a PUT request on Yii.

The method getPut() calls the method getRestParams(), that method tries to parse the rawBody.
The method getRawBody() returns the value of file_get_contents('php://input')

The function file_get_contents('php://input') returns the value:

```
{"foo": "foo content", "bar": "bar content"}
```

The function getRestParams() tries to parse this content calling the function mb_parse_str (https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php#L290)

```
mb_parse_str($this->getRawBody(), $result);
```

But this returns:

```
Array
(
    [{"foo": "foo content", "bar": "bar content"}] => 
)
```

I haven't much experience with PHP, much less with the Yii framework.

To me, it seems to be a bug in the framework, but it is likely that I'm wrong.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Looks correct to me. What do you expect? Consider you should use URL encoded parameters, not JSON, so maybe what you really want to feed in stdin is `foo=foo%20content&bar=bar%20content`.

Comment: As @ntd say, it looks correct: it returns what expected, see more on the official page http://php.net/manual/it/function.mb-parse-str.php

Comment: Hi guys, that json is my request body. Looks incorrect to me to send these params in the URL, considering that I'm sending a PUT request.

Comment: The function actually returns what is expected, but it seems to me that the framework should not use it in this case.

Comment: @pedrocalgaro We are talking about **how** you should encode your data, not **where** (and, in fact, in the `PUT` request the URL encoded params should be sent in the request body). Keep in mind [RFC 2616](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616) (the RFC that defines what a PUT request is) is dated 1999, a couple of years before JSON was even conceived.

Comment: Ok @ntd, I got it. That JSON is accessed by the function file_get_contents('php://input'). From my understanding, that function read the body of the request. So, if I need to change the encode of the body value, should I change something in my client request?

Comment: Correct, `php://input` is the HTTP body. I suppose in the client side you use JavaScript, so sending JSON is quite convenient. I'd try to decode JSON on the server side using @Olim's approach that, AFAICT, overrides `getRestParams` to expect JSON instead of URL-encoded data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect all the requests to have JSON data use this simple solution:

Extend base request component:

```
class HttpJsonRequest extends CHttpRequest
{

    protected $_restParams;

    public function getRestParams()
    {
        if ($this->_restParams === null) {
            $this->_restParams = CJSON::decode($this->getRawBody());
        }

        return $this->_restParams;
    }

}
```

And include this class in config main:

```
'components' => array(
    ...
    'request' => array('class' => 'HttpJsonRequest'),
    ...
)
```